# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes') [Node.js and socket.io]

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have run into an issue in my server code where when it checks to see if the user is in a chatroom, it raises a error.

*TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes') [Node.js and socket.io]*

```
for (let key of Object.keys(rooms)){
  console.log("ru "+socket.roomsJoined)
  if ((socket.roomsJoined).includes(key)){
     userdata.push([rooms[key][0],[rooms[key][2]]]);
  }
}
```

rooms is a javascript object and the key is the room id. socket.roomsJoined contains an array with the room ids the user is in.

Thanks for the help

I've tried lots of stuff but nothing works. Even the debugger in Replit doesn't help.

Comment: That means that `socket.roomsJoined` is undefined. What do you see in the `console.log`?

Comment: @Barmar the console.log returns the ids of the rooms you are in. the error occurs after a bunch of server requests. it seems like the data is not persisting or something

Comment: Variables don't change by themselves.  node.js variables persist, since there's just one server process with all the variables. You'll need to post a [mre] that shows how you're setting `socket`.

Comment: This is how I'm setting up the variable when a user connects: socket.roomsJoined = [];
I add room ids with this when a user creates a new chat room: (socket.roomsJoined).push(rNum);
That's the only other spots I'm using roomsJoined

Comment: There are multiple clients. How do you persist `socket` when switching clients?

Comment: Is it supposed to be done by `socket.io`? The problem may be that you're not using it correctly. Add your code to the question (not a comment).

Comment: socket variables can be used to store client data for each client. i've used them in other server programs. also, should i put all of my code in the question?

Comment: Put enough code to demonstrate the problem, not all the code.